# Insert multiple rows into database using stored procedure with foreach loop

Tags: mysql, arrays, stored-procedures, foreach

Here's my  code in calling my stored procedure. It always save only 1 value.

```
public function getClientTerminal(){
        $form = $this->getUserData();

        $DAO = $this->getDAO('DAO');
        $result=$DAO->query('getClientTerminal',$form);
        $y = sizeof($result);

    $i = 0;
    DO
    {
     $form['terminal_id'] = $result[$i];
    $DAO = $this->getDAO('DAO');
    return $this->status(0,true,'insert.success',$DAO->query('insertTerminals',$form));
    $i++;
    }
    WHILE ($i < $y);

    }
```

Comment: What do you think `return` does?

Comment: it only returns the result of the statement.

Comment: right. My question is - do you realize what `return` does?

Comment: I just read what return really does. ohmygod i change the return function and replace it with a variable. You're a life saver! Thank you so much for pointing that out to me.